# How to connect thin clients to a windows network?

Tags: ip-address, thin-client, windows-embedded-7

I have a few new HP t574o thin clients that have windows 7 embedded edition pre-installed. I want them to be able to connect to our existing network which has a windows 7 ultimate edition machine running a server.

Traditionally we have been manually setting the IP address of the clients, but with the OS installed on the thin clients there is no option that allows us to do that.

How can I manually or automatically assign IP addresses to these thin clients so that they can access a web application hosted on the server?

Additionally I'd like to connect a webcam and a fingerprint device to this but I don't know how to install the drivers for those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely can set a static IP on the HP T5740 - in fact, for the most part, they work just like full fat Windows. What problem are you having? I presume you've been logging in as admin and committing / disabling the write filter?

The same applies for your drivers - however, you may need to alter the "TEMP" and "TMP" system variables before you attempt to install. This should all be documented in the HP setup guides.

Comment: Could you post links to the HP manual or add some more detail to the answer. I'll accept this answer

Comment: You ARE joking, right? I know the HP site can be a bit overwhelming but that's just pure and complete laziness.

Comment: Man you guys are harsh wit hthe downvotes and all. If all the info was in one place it would help someone else with a similar question.
These thin clients can be overwhelming when you have to set them up for the first time.

Comment: @nikhil you can check this hp link for basic uses of t5740 http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02039010.pdf